# My breakpoint is not working please give me some suggestions as to why not

Tags: iphone

While debugging the program my breakpoint is not working, so please give me some advice so that it can work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've tried to use the breakpoint on unreachable code? Try setting your breakpoint somewhere before the point you want to reach and try stepping from there to see if the point is actually reached.

Comment: yes i have already setting my break point at the reachable code but it is not stopped any where.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Reasons could be.
1. After changes in the code you have not built the libraries properly so the breakpoint is not pointing to the right location in the code.
2. If you are putting a breakpoint in a library then make sure the library is build and is built in Debug mode.
3. Clean full environment and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Open XCode preferences and in the Debugging tab, un-check "Load symbols lazily", this caught me out when I first started iPhone developement. Then again, it might be for any of the other reasons that people have already mentioned.